# Access denied on vsftps while writing a file

Tags: linux, ubuntu, vpn, ftp

I installed vsftpd on ubuntu 13.04 server
write is enabled
im able to login as authenticated user - i own /home/luby directory and it's chmod 7777, when trying to write to it i get 550 Access is denied. why?

Comment: Can you post your config file? Check your umask setting in vsftpd.conf and whether or not you have "cmds_allowed" or similar lines in it

Answer (score 0):

Did you enable writes in your /etc/vsftpd.conf ? Writes are disabled by default, so if you just installed the package then you need to edit your config file and restart the service. You can refer to the link below, the information for enabling writes is located in the "User Authenticated FTP Configuration" section.

[Ubuntu FTP Server Guide](https://help.ubuntu.com/10.04/serverguide/ftp-server.html)